# PyBrain error estimate does not change over time when training the network

Tags: python-2.7, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, pybrain

I am using PyBrain 0.3 (with python 2.7.9), and when I train my network with the BackpropTrainer, there is no change is the total error, even after some 10 - 20 iterations.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
path = "../pckld_ROIs/master_r19_7_5_emissivity_sub.pkl"
roi = RegionsOfInterest(path)
roi.set_aggregate(True)
net = ClassificationNet(roi, ['soil'], neigborhood_size=3)
net.neural_net.randomize()
net.set_trainer(learning_rate=0.1, verbose=True, momentum=0.1, weight_decay=0.01)
net.train_network(max_epochs=300, verbose=True)
```

Where `RegionsOfInterest` is structure for holding, and structuring the data points.

```
def set_trainer(self, learning_rate=0.01, lrdecay=1.0,
                momentum=0., verbose=False, batch_learning=False,
                weight_decay=0.):
        """
            Sets the trainer. If the data has been split, it uses the training data as data for the back-propagation
            algorithm. If not, it uses the entire data set.
        :param learning_rate:       The rate in which the parameters are changed into the direction of the gradient.
        :param lrdecay:             How much the learning rate decreases per epoch. Multiplicative!
        :param momentum:            The weight of the previous time-step's gradient is affecting the next iteration.
        :param verbose:             Toggles verbose mode. Default is off.
        :param batch_learning:      Will be parameters be updated at the end of the epoch, or continuously? The default
                                    is continuously.
        :param weight_decay:        How much the weighs are decreasing. 0 corresponds to no decrease.
        :type learning_rate:        float
        :type lrdecay:              float
        :type momentum:             float
        :type verbose:              bool
        :type batch_learning:       bool
        :type weight_decay:         float
        :return: None
        """
        if self.training_data is not None:
            self.trainer = BackpropTrainer(self.neural_net, self.training_data,
                                           learning_rate, lrdecay, momentum, verbose,
                                           batch_learning, weight_decay)
        else:
            self.trainer = BackpropTrainer(self.neural_net, self.training_data,
                                           learning_rate, lrdecay, momentum, verbose,
                                           batch_learning, weight_decay)



def train_network(self,
                  max_epochs=-1,
                  verbose=False,
                  continue_epochs=10,
                  validation_proportion=0.25,
                  force_split=False):
        """
            Trains the network until the error rate converges.
        :param max_epochs:              The maximum number of epochs the network is trained. The default is to not set a
                                        maximum.
        :param verbose:                 Toggles verbose mode or not. The default is not.
        :param continue_epochs:         How much longer the training should go on if we find a minimum in the error.
        :param validation_proportion:   The proportion that will be used for validation. The default is 25%, given that
                                        the 'self.validation_data' has not been set.
        :param force_split:             If the 'self.validation_data' as been set, we can force another split on the
                                        training data.
        :type max_epochs:               int
        :type verbose:                  bool
        :type continue_epochs:          int
        :type validation_proportion:    float
        :type force_split:              bool
        :return:                        None
        """
        if max_epochs <= 0:
            # We don't give it a stop criteria for time.
            if self.validation_data is not None:
                # We have already set aside some of the data for validation
                if force_split:
                    # Screw that! I want the data to be split again!
                    self.trainer.trainUntilConvergence(self.training_data, None, verbose,
                                                       continue_epochs, validation_proportion)
                else:
                    self.trainer.trainUntilConvergence(self.training_data, None, verbose, continue_epochs, 1)
            else:
                # We have no validation data set
                self.trainer.trainUntilConvergence(self.data_set, None, verbose, continue_epochs, validation_proportion)
        else:
            # We have a stop criteria.
            if self.validation_data is not None:
                # We have already split the data into a validation set, and a training set.
                if force_split:
                    # Screw that! I want the data to be split again
                    self.trainer.trainUntilConvergence(self.training_data, max_epochs, verbose,
                                                       continue_epochs, validation_proportion)
                else:
                    self.trainer.trainUntilConvergence(self.training_data, max_epochs, verbose, continue_epochs, 1)
            else:
                # We do not have a validation data set.
                self.trainer.trainUntilConvergence(self.data_set, max_epochs, verbose,
                                                   continue_epochs, validation_proportion)
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the data, but one possibility is that you're trying to do something impossible.  For example, if the target for an output is 10, and your output layer is neurons that only go from 0 to 1, then the error will get stuck at 9.  Without having your input data to work with I'm not sure, but you might check that your inputs and targets are scaled appropriately.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about to change how the nodes work?